# Why jQuery code run from a chrome extension behaves differently that jQuery code run from the browser console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that auto-fills certain fields on a HTML form (but doesn't submit). It works just fine when I try to fill normal `<input>` fields, but some fields have some kind of post-input validation - which doesn't happen when I use `$(obj).val(value)`. And it's those fields that I can't make to "trigger".

What's interesting is that it *works just fine when I type the jquery commands directly into the browser console*. But when I execute the code from my extension, some events just don't launch.

I've tried using the `.trigger` function with all kinds of events, including obviously `change`, but also `focusin`, `click`, `focus`, `focusout`. This works when executed from the browser.

I thought it's a problem with the jQuery version, so I made sure the browser and the extension use the same version, but that also didn't work.

The page in question is under this [link](https://www.verivox.de/signup/energie/tarif/strom/-AYAAAAeMjAxODExMjB1MTUzODZyZHBjY2x2M2lldzE5NDczAQAAAItSCQABAA9iY2RlZmdoaWprMDgwNjQHWndpY2thdQpOZXVwbGFuaXR61AsBAOgDAAAoqAoAYCQBAAEwAwECAAAA-----wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP---------------w==/?ori=-AYAAAAeMjAxODExMjB1MTUzODZyZHBjY2x2M2lldzE5NDczDmFiY2VmZ2hpajA4MDY06AMAAAJoMAAAAAAB1AsBAAEBAAsA--%2BLUgkAAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAAAAwAAAAAAP--AwAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAi0x----------8AAAAAAAD----------wAAAAAAAAAAAAI%3D&ranking=2&site_id=2&tariff_id=698408&vx_user_id=-1&position0=True&Source_ID=1788&CampaignId=20181120u15386rdpcclv3iew19473).

There's a field "Date of Birth" (marked as Geburtsdatum), that's the one I have a problem with. The code I'm using is this:

```
const dateOfBirthId = "#ContactData_DayOfBirth_clone";
const $dbf = $(dateOfBirthId);
$dbf.trigger("focusin");
$dbf.trigger("click");
$dbf.trigger("focus");
$(dateOfBirthId).val("12.05.1970");
$dbf.trigger("change");
$dbf.trigger("focusout");
```

(there's the German date format, DD.MM.YYYY)

The original code I tried was just `$(dateOfBirthId).val("12.05.1970").trigger("change");` but that also didn't work.

The big code block works if you execute it line by line in the chrome console. But not in the extension.

The error in question is that once the date has been "pasted" (it's visibly there), it's not actually there. If you hover over the field in question, the value will get overwritten by the placeholder, and even if you do not do that, you can't submit the form because it thinks the field is empty.

If you execute the code in the chrome console that doesn't happen, once you hover over the field the value stays there.

Comment: Content scripts run in isolated world so jQuery can't trigger events in the page listeners. Either use the standard `dispatchEvent` or [switch to execCommand](/a/57900849).